# Use while loop to add many objects to arraylist

Tags: java, bluej

Taking an intro course to Java, using BlueJ.

Have two objects, and object called **account** with relevant details and an ArrayList called **bankAccounts** containing accounts.

I am tasked with adding multiple **accounts** to **bankAccounts** using a while loop.  Adding an object to an arraylist is easy, however BlueJ prompts you to select the account.

I've no idea how to automate this process, trying something along the lines of:

```
public void addMultipleAccounts()
   {
       reader = new InputReader();

       System.out.println("How many accounts would you like to add?");
       int accountsToAdd = Integer.parseInt(reader.getInput());

       while (accountsToAdd>0) {
           System.out.println("Which account would you like to add?");
           String accountToAdd = reader.getInput();
           bankAccounts.add(accountToAdd);
           accountsToAdd--;
       }
   }
```

Which obviously doesn't work.  InputReader() is a prof supplied class that uses Scanner to collect Strings.

I'm certain there is an easy way to do this I am missing but I just can't find it...I don't know how to prompt a user for input for an object, BlueJ has always done it automatically.

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't doing what you want because your trying to add a string into an arrayList of type Account

Comment: Yep...
I don't know how to prompt a user for input for an object, BlueJ has always done it automatically.

Comment: You need to prompt them for the different things needed to construct the object, construct it yourself then add it to the list

Comment: Wish I could mark that as answer.  Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Something {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<aClass> list = new ArrayList<aClass>();
        String first, second;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int repeat;
        System.out.println("How many items would you like to enter?");
        repeat = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your first parameter");
            first = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter your second parameter");
            second = scanner.next();
            aClass temp = new aClass(first,second); //This will be put into the array
            list.add(temp);
        }

    }

}

class aClass{

    private String something, somethingelse;

    public aClass(String str1, String str2){
        something = str1;
        somethingelse = str2;
    }

}
```

In this case your 'aClass is your account class and list is your BackAccounts arraylist. obviously you need to change the parameters to match your account class but this is how you would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what do you're trying to implement.
Maybe you should think of a better way to do this control.
I tried to build a code for something I thought was what do you want.

```
public void addMultipleAccounts() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many accounts would you like to add?");
    int accountsToAdd = s.nextInt();

    while (accountsToAdd > 0) {
        System.out.println("Which account would you like to add?");
        String accountToAdd = s.nextLine();
        bankAccounts.add(accountToAdd);
        accountsToAdd--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that's my problem is I can't figure out a good way to do it.  I can figure out the code...

This won't work because bankAccounts.add adds an Account object, not a String.  I don't know how I can prompt the user for input in Account form.